# Show Bootstrap Alert Message 'onsubmit' in Twig file

Tags: wordpress, forms, twig, bootstrap-5, onsubmit

I am a bit of a noob yet but would like the simplest way to show a [Bootstrap5 Alert](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/) upon a form submission without having to get into JavaScript and all that complication.

Currently this (an example) of what I am showing in the head of my html form in WordPress using Twig:

`<form name="Delivery_Quote" method="post" action="{{options.delivery.web_hook}}"` `enctype="multipart/form-data" id="deliveryquote" onsubmit="return` `submitDelivery_Quote()">`

How would I add a bootstrap alert such as: `Thank-you your request has been send! We will contact you shortly`

Thank-you for any suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
  Thank-you your request has been send! We will contact you shortly
</div>
```

Colors you can change, check bootstrap official page

Comment: '<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert"> Thank-you your request has been send! We will contact you shortly </div>'

Comment: I just dropped this inside the <form> </form> tags but it just displays right away, I only want it to display upon submit?